# HttpClient.SendAsync on Blazor WASM returns empty HttpResponseMessage although Fiddler shows that correct response was received

Tags: blazor, httpclient, webassembly, httpresponsemessage, sendasync

My Blazor page code:

```
private async Task OnSendSMSClick()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseAddress);
        request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
        request.SetBrowserRequestCache(BrowserRequestCache.NoCache);
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret)
            });
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.Content = content;
        RequestOutput = request.ToString();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        
        ResponseOutput = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
```

response always returns empty although I see on Fiddler that the actual result is returned. On Google Chrome, I see that the server responded 200 with correct headers but somehow Chrome says "Failed to load response data".

[image: Fiddler SS]

No errors on Chrome and I get a 200 response but it somehow fails to show the response content:

[image: Chrome 200]

[image: Chrome fails to display response content]

And you can see in the debugger that the response object is empty..

[image: Empty response object]

How can I fix that, what I am missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Blazor has an issue with sites requiring CORS ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24080)).

Unfortunately, there's nothing that can be done on the Blazor client side.
The only solution I've found is to either [disable CORS on the server](https://www.abhith.net/blog/iis-disable-cors/) or set up a proxy server outside of Blazor.